# Beginner C++ Windows D2D1Circle Sample from MSDN Problem

Tags: c++, msdn, sample

So I was just going through the basic Windows Programming guide over at MSDN and attempted to do the D2D1Circle Sample in Module 3. The problem I encountered was an error my VC++ 2008 was throwing. 
" 'CreateWindowExA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'PCWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'"

So, figuring that I had made a slight error while typing the code in I downloaded the sample code rar and opened it up and it threw the exact same error. Any ideas on how I can fix this so it will work. Also, does the fact that I'm programming on a x64 bit machine have anything to do with why it won't work? I know pointers carry different sized values dependent on the machine and both the parameters being called are pointers.

Update @ Jollymorphic: In the first few modules, the MSDN tutorial was saying that there really isn't any reason to continue using ascii since unicode covers ascii and also supports all other languages like Chinese, Japanese, etc. Wouldn't implementing your solution cause my program to only support ascii and subsequently not allow support for east asian languages?

Answer (score 4):

A PCWSTR is a pointer to wide (16-bit) characters.  An LPCSTR is a pointer to regular (8-bit) characters.  Your project probably is set to generate code based on the UNICODE character set.  If you open the properties for your project in Visual Studio, and then navigate to the "General" page, you'll see a "Character Set" property.  If it is currently set to "Use Unicode character set," then you can change it to "Use Multi-Byte character set," and your string literals will be generated as 8-bit character strings.